# Media library - Limit images to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, filters, advanced-custom-fields, media-library

Is there some wordpress magic/plugin that will make the media library only show images that were uploaded to a specific custom post type?
I have a custom post type called "artists", I want, when admin click to upload/attach an image, that the media library popup only show images that have been uploaded to the artists custom type, and not the entire site.

I use the ACF plugin for handling custom fields, and custom post types ui.
Is this possible?

Comment: Let me check if I understand it correctly... So you want to change media library popup in such way that it shows only images that were uploaded to specific CPT if you open it while editing this CPT. And it should work like always when you're editing other post types?

Comment: What's the context/reasoning behind doing this? Are you trying to implement an artist picker?

Comment: The use case in my case is a large WordPress site where not everyone edits the same post types. It's much tidier (and useful) to show the most recent related file uploads as opposed to uploads from all over the site, so that files that need to be reused can easily be picked.

(I didn't ask this question originally but added the bounty. I'm trying to do exactly what Krzysiek described (thanks for the answer, I'll try it))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I get your problem right, but... Maybe this will help you...

Media uploader gets attachments with simple `WP_Query`, so you can use many filters to modify it's contents.

The only problem is that you can't query posts with specific CPT as parent using `WP_Query` arguments... So, we will have to use `posts_where` and `posts_join` filters.

To be sure, that we'll change only media uploader's query, we'll use `ajax_query_attachments_args`.

And this is how it looks, when combined:

```
function my_posts_where($where) {
    global $wpdb;

    $post_id = false;
    if ( isset($_POST['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if ( $post ) {
            $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND my_post_parent.post_type = %s ", $post->post_type);
        }
    }

    return $where;
}

function my_posts_join($join) {
    global $wpdb;

    $join .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} as my_post_parent ON ({$wpdb->posts}.post_parent = my_post_parent.ID) ";

    return $join;
}


function my_bind_media_uploader_special_filters($query) {
    add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
    add_filter('posts_join', 'my_posts_join');

    return $query;
}
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', 'my_bind_media_uploader_special_filters');
```

When you open media uploader dialog while editing post (post/page/CPT), you'll see only images attached to this specific post type.

If you'd like it to work only for one specific post type (let's say pages), you'll have to change condition in `my_posts_where` function like so:

```
function my_posts_where($where) {
    global $wpdb;

    $post_id = false;
    if ( isset($_POST['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if ( $post && 'page' == $post->post_type ) {  // you can change 'page' to any other post type
            $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND my_post_parent.post_type = %s ", $post->post_type);
        }
    }

    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment, I deleted my answer so as not to confuse anyone. +1 on yours.

Answer (score 0):

Display only the images of the property when editing the featured image

```
function my_bind_media_uploader_special_filters($query) 
{

    add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
    return $query;
}

add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args','my_bind_media_uploader_special_filters');

function my_posts_where ($where) 
{

    global $wpdb;
    $post_id = false;
    if ( isset($_POST['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if ( $post && 'property' == $post->post_type) {
            $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND id in (select distinct meta_value from 
            wpdb_postmeta where meta_key='fave_property_images' and post_id = $post_id)", 
            $post->post_type);
        }
    }
    return $where;
}
```