# Which Hook? Hide attachments from specific post types in media library

Tags: hooks, media-library

as the title implies - I would like to suppress attachments of a specific post type(s) from showing up in the "Media Library"

Not asking for a code example, but if someone can point me to the right hook it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I recall @KrzysiekDróżdż doing something similar [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/190880/26350)

Comment: @birigire -this was extraordinarily helpful. Wasn't exactly what I wanted to accomplish but did outline how to hook into the proper process. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the media library you can use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook targeting `upload.php` by means of `$pagenow`, a `global` variable, or even better, because globals are the devils child, by means of [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen). I'm assuming you want to target the media modal tab too - because targeting only one, but not the other, doesn't make much sense after all -, you can do that via the [`ajax_query_attachments_args`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/ajax_query_attachments_args) hook.

Comment: Ok great. I'll look into this and will come back and accept the answer if this works out. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, and sure, just take your time. One more hint, you are looking for the attachments parents - `post_parent` -, which are the posts the files have been uploaded to, of course you have to sort out the correct ones, by post type in your case. If you have those, preferably an array of ids, then you can exclude them from the query. @BrandtSolovij

Comment: thanks again - mostly we have some version control around posttypes and some are focused around attachments - those attachments have found their way into the media library "browse" modals. I simply wish to suppress those - so get_current_screen + pre_get_posts right now feels like the fit @ialocin

Comment: No problem, what I said isn't mutually exclusive, on the contrary, you need to do both, determine what you want to exclude and then target the query to actually exclude, in some way or another. Ping me if you are not getting there, but I won't be able to answer by sometime next week. @BrandtSolovij

Comment: ajax_query_attachments_args was where to start. Thanks!